# 500 (Internal Server) Error in codeigniter project

Tags: codeigniter

My site working properly but in some pages this error occurs.
i also changed my .htaccess file then also same error . My .htaccess file code is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

Comment: are you using sessions?

Comment: Add `/` before last `$1`. Also, add RewriteBase with its value somewhere at beginning of the file. Check apache log errors.